# What is this medicinal plant?

Tags: shrubs

Someone suggested to consume this plant to help in my breathing problems. But I don't want to consume it without knowing what it is ? It looks like a medicinal plant, but what is it ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: First thought would be narrow leaf plantain.  Really need some scale.  What was the habitat?

Comment: Is the stem square?  If so, then, user76900 is correct.  It would be mint.  Please send a few more pictures.  I am also thinking Milkweed...

Answer (score 1):

Where was it growing? When was it harvested? It looks most like Wild Mint (Mentha arvensis), but also like Slender Mountain Mint (Pycnanthemum tenuifolium). Mints are frequently used for respiratory support.